# Plupload filename problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I ask here in the hope that some members will be familiar enough with 'plupload' to help.
This little Jquery script is on the way to making my file-upload problems go away, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Question:
I can upload large files using plupload, but when the appear on the server the name has changed to gibberish,

```
EG p163g1k1er15n310bi18bq1af61rc21.zip
```

From my experience with basic upload forms my assumption is that it is writing out a temp filename with the intention of renaming it to the original filename when the chunked sections have been put back together, but for some reason it may not be doing this.

I have changed the permission on the folder to 777, so I'm reasonably sure this isn't the issue.

The runtime being used is Flash (I require the chunking feature). It's version 1.4.3.2

As always, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a configuration option to generate unique file names instead of using the actual file name.

From the [docs](http://www.plupload.com/documentation.php):

> **unique_names**
>   Generate unique filenames when uploading. This will generate unqiue
>   filenames for the files so that they
>   don't for example collide with
>   existing ones on the server.

Make sure this option is not enabled in your configuration (it is not by default). There are still some file name cleaning routines run by the default included php upload script...

```
// Clean the fileName for security reasons
$fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '', $fileName);
```

...and an underscore is always appended with a number if the file exists (regardless of configuration), like `filename_2.jpg`, but aside from that it should not be altering your file names.

**EDIT**: I've been searching the [forums](http://www.plupload.com/punbb/index.php) for a solution but coming up short, my last piece of advice is to try the HTML5 runtime, to see if this is related to the Flash runtime somehow, as there have been [some issues](http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=266) with previous versions. If all else fails, post on the forum - the admins there are very responsive. Best of luck, please post a solution here if you find it.

Comment: Thanks, I will look for this and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I commented out the line in question as you suggested, but unfortunately I am still getting the same odd filenames on the server.

Comment: I have checked that the edit is on the server, and have used a different browser to avoid any caching issues. If you don't mind could you tell me how to check the version and runtime

Comment: @Andrew: The version should be in the included changelog if not other places, and the runtime will be shown as a tooltip when hovering the upload queue (if you are using it), also it should be defined in your config (probably HTML5 is being used). Version is also in the source of `plupload.js`

Comment: Thanks Wesley, the runtime being used is Flash (I require the chunking feature). It's version 1.4.3.2

Comment: For me, same behavior. The limit seems to be 19MiB - 19 and below, filename is left intact. >19MiB - filename is changed to `file_xxxxxxxxxxxxx`. To check, edit the third (else-statement) stament below `// Get a file name` in `upload.php`, your filename will be this. Somehow the filename does not seem to be passed to the `$_REQUEST["name"]` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Ploploader uses a variable called "unique_names"; in my case this was set to TRUE, however to preserve the actual filenames it should be set to false. Solution came from the Pluploader forum.

Answer (score 0):

To keep original filename, if you use the upload.php provided by plupload then I had to change upload.php line 34 from

```
$fileName = isset($_REQUEST['name']) ? $_REQUEST['name'] : '';
```

to

```
$fileName = isset($_FILES['file']["name"]) ? $_FILES['file']["name"] : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. An another solution is to inject real file name as a new input into FormData object. 
(I am using chrome and HTML5 runtime!)
in `plupload.html5.js` file find the creation of object `O = new FormData();`
and 
add some injections with

```
var oFileName = $("input[name='oFileName']").val();
O.append("oFileName", V.name);
```

After this adding get the real file name in your server side (for upload.php)

```
$oFileName = $_REQUEST["oFileName"];
```