# Plupload file rename

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-s3, plupload

I am using Plupload to upload to S3; My problem is that I want to change names of files, so when they reside in S3 they will be changed to a format I want. I managed to retrieve the file name of files uploaded by the function:

```
 FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
                    for (var i in files) {
                        files[i].name = files[i].name.split('_').join(' ').trim();
                        alert('Selected files: ' + files[i].name);

                    }
```

the file name changes in the control but when I check the S3 the file is unchanged.

I made sure unique_names property is false and rename property to true; but did not work any help?

Comment: I have the same problem. However with my code it seems as though some files are renamed but others retain their original name.

Comment: Another suggest is here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534734/plupload-filename-problem/35477481#35477481](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534734/plupload-filename-problem/35477481#35477481)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem i.e. using pluploader for S3 and wanted to normalize file names before uploading. Unfortunately 'Files' param appears to be read-only and any changes to file's name doesn't show up in the submitted form.

But if we change the 'key' param to an exact string (normalized name) it will cause S3 to save it with a different name. We can create a normalized name and use it in the 'key' param in the multipart_param in the 'FileAdded' callback.

```
....
FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
  console.log("Uploader.FilesAdded ", up, files);

  var file = files[0];

  //Replace unwanted characters with "_"
  var new_name = file.name.replace(/[^a-z0-9\.]+/gi,"_").toLowerCase();

  console.log("Changing file name to ", file.name);

  //Create multipart_params here (or just set the 'key' and 'Filename')
  var multipart_params =  {
    'key': config.key + new_name, // *instead of ${filename}
    'Filename':  config.key + new_name,
    'acl': config.acl,
    'Content-Type': '',
    'AWSAccessKeyId' : config.accessId,
    'policy': config.policy,
    'signature': config.signature
  };

 //
 up.settings.multipart_params = multipart_params;
}
....
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the requirement to add a user-definable prefix to *all* the files in the upload queue *just before* executing the multipart upload to S3. In my case, the prefix could be edited at any time before starting the upload - so using the **FilesAdded** event wasn't acceptable.

The solution that worked for me was to use the **BeforeUpload** which fires for each file in the queue just before starting the upload.

```
 BeforeUpload: function(up, file) {

     //Change the filename          
     file.name = appendUniqueId(file.name);
     file.name = addPrefix(file.name);

     var params = up.settings.multipart_params;
     params.key = file.name;
     params.Filename = file.name;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with unique_names:true with rename:true. It works for me.

Comment: for some reason it did not work for me...could it be the 'Key:${filename}' in the multipart_params?

Answer (score 0):

The only fully working solution which I have found to this problem is to make use of the property `multipart_params` on the Plupload uploader.

The code I am using is;

```
uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function (up, file) {
    uploader.settings.multipart_params = { 'renamedFileName': 'yourRenamedFileName' };
});
```

Then when you are processing your image, you can then request this from the posted information;

**c# code**

```
var renamedFileName = context.Request["renamedFileName"].ToString();
```

For your code you could try;

```
uploader.bind('BeforeUpload', function (up, file) {
    uploader.settings.multipart_params = { 'renamedFileName': file.name.split('_').join(' ').trim(); };
});
```

You can then use this additional information to rename the file on your server.

Comment: Thank you for the respond; however I am using S3; so I do not think I can make use of the attribute. Looks like the only way is to change the file name after it is uploaded  somehow...thnx again

Comment: Another suggest is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534734/plupload-filename-problem/35477481#35477481

Comment: This is indeed the best answer and probably the correct way to do it. @ibininja with S3 you simply use `up.settings.multipart_params.key = 'filename'` instead of re-defining the entire object. For some reason, that only works and gives the correct result in the `BeforeUpload` event. Look at @Collie's example for your specific scenario.